# Synology NAS webstation image resize

Tags: php, image, resize, nas, synology

So I'm currently using the following script on my synology nas webstation to resize images one at a time. It is being called by a post function on another page every time the previous request has been handled.

```
$originalFile = 'img1.jpg';
$smallFile = 'img1_small.jpg';
$percentage = 0.2;
$mktime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', filemtime($originalFile));
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalFile);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($originalFile);

    if(function_exists("exif_read_data")){

        $exif = @exif_read_data($originalFile);

            if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {

                switch($exif['Orientation']) {
                    case 8:
                            $img = imagerotate($img,90,0);
                                list($height, $width) = getimagesize($originalFile);
                                break;
                    case 3:
                        $img = imagerotate($img,180,0);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        $img = imagerotate($img,-90,0);
                        list($height, $width) = getimagesize($originalFile);
                        break;
                }
            }
    }
    $newWidth = ceil($percentage * $width);
    $newHeight = ceil($percentage * $height);

    $resized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($resized, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($resized, $smallFile, 100);
    imagedestroy($resized);
```

The images are images coming from a camera so they are almost he greatest quality you can get. 
The issue here is that i'm not able to run imagick on my nas. I would not know how to install this for php.

Is there any smart way to speed up the process I am doing here?
BTW. I am running some sql scripts as well so I'd like to keep doing this using php.

Answer (score 1):

There is a community repository, which has imagick.
https://synocommunity.com/
https://synocommunity.com/package/imagemagick

> Step 1 Log into your NAS as administrator and go to Main Menu →
>   Package Center → Settings and set Trust Level to Synology Inc. and
>   trusted publishers.
>
> Step 2 In the Package Sources tab, click Add, type SynoCommunity as
>   Name and http://packages.synocommunity.com/ as Location and then press
>   OK to validate.
>
> Step 3 Go back to the Package Center and enjoy SynoCommunity's
>   packages in the Community tab.

Depending on your Synology, it might be an idea to use Docker for this task, instead of installing directly Imagick onto your synology.

Comment: This package does not work with the PHP package on a synology nas, hence, this package will not do as asked in my question.

Comment: Theoeretically you should be able to call the executable, through exec.
But yes the code as such has to be adapted. Since there is no build available, I would go that way.